# SQL Weighted averages of multiple rows -

Tags: mysql, sql

How would you go about to find the *real* weighted average of multiple rows:

By *real* weighted, I mean like this calculator: https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/math/weighted-average-calculator.html (and not by multiplying value with weight).

[image]

The weight for each answer is set in `answers` and values for each question in child-table `answer_items`. We want the weighted average for each `question` (a,b,c,d). We know what questions to look for in advance.

The query will include between 2 and 500k answers (so preferably a speedy solution :) )

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `weight` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `answers` (`id`, `weight`) VALUES
(1, '0.7'),
(2, '1'),
(3, '0.7'),
(4, '0.9');

CREATE TABLE `answer_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `answer_items` (`id`, `answer_id`, `question`, `value`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'a', 2),
(2, 1, 'b', 4),
(3, 1, 'c', 2),
(4, 1, 'd', 3),
(5, 2, 'a', 4),
(6, 2, 'b', 2),
(7, 2, 'c', 4),
(8, 2, 'd', 1),
(9, 3, 'a', 3),
(10, 3, 'b', 4),
(11, 3, 'c', 1),
(12, 3, 'd', 5),
(13, 4, 'a', 5),
(14, 4, 'b', 2),
(15, 4, 'c', 3),
(16, 4, 'd', 3);


ALTER TABLE `answers`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `answer_items`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `answers`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

ALTER TABLE `answer_items`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=17;
```

Comment: The code sample is MySQL so I removed the Postgres tag (although it makes little difference to the answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can multiply the value times the weight and then divide by the sum of the weights.  For the weighted average by question:

```
select question, sum(ai.value * a.weight) / sum(a.weight)
from answer_items ai join
     answers a
     on ai.answer_id = a.id
group by question;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56823b44fc2a9276622afe3c3c2b5794) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Nice one - works like a charm. Follow up question: 

1: Group_by question & user_id and count answers (not items) for each user and total. Possbile? 

2: Posibility to group the response in array for each user `[ [user_id, [[question_id, average] ]`

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e21ca94e5d0280261a5fe338be339cd8

Comment: @LineinLinus . . . Follow up questions should be new *questions*, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Somethin like:

```
SELECT
   SUM(value * weight) / SUM (weight)
FROM
   answers
JOIN
   answer_items
ON
   answer_items.answer_id = answers.id
```

(edit: and obviously include the question and GROUP BY question, as in the previous answer for the SUM aggregation, as per the previous answer. D'oh)